# sed throws bad flag in substitute command: 'l' in Mac

Tags: linux, macos, unix, sed

> sed: 1: "filename": bad flag in substitute command: 'l'

sed throws this when i am trying to change some substring:

```
sed -i '/string1/ s/string2/string3/g' filename
```

Comment: (1) Show us the command that you were actually using, not the phony command with the `string1`, `string2` etc. (2) Are you on linux, as the tag says, or are you on OSX?

Comment: sed -i  '/rate="100"/ s/tax="15"/tax="25"/g' this is the actual command I used and I am on OSX

Comment: Try: `sed -i "" '/rate="100"/ s/tax="15"/tax="25"/g'`

Comment: The [`-i` option is being used incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use).  `sed -i '' '/string1/ s/string2/string3/g' filename` will have the intended behavior, but note that the manual warns against using the `-i` option without creating a backup file.